# 'If button is clicked' on a button already assigned to a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, button

I have this code, including buttons, each of which calls a ajax function when clicked, and a popup which is filled with the content from the ajax function.

```
<script>
function loadindex1() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //select the div to change by id
            document.getElementById("tt_popup").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    //select the file to show next
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "stop_1.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function loadindex2() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //select the div to change by id
            document.getElementById("tt_popup").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    //select the file to show next
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "stop_2.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="popup" id="tt_popup" >
      <p>Have patience...</p>
    </div> <!-- /popup -->

    <div id="tt_div1"></div>

    <a href="#tt_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn  ui-corner-all" onclick="loadindex1()" id="button_stop1" data-transition="flip" >
       <img src="/Pictures/Location_original.png" alt="Problems?" id="loc_img" />
    </a>
    <a href="#tt_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn  ui-corner-all" onclick="loadindex2()" id="button_stop2" data-transition="flip" >
       <img src="/Pictures/Location_original.png" alt="Problems?" id="loc_img" />
    </a>
```

I now want to also know which button is clicked, so I can do something with that. I want use local-storage, and make a panel where a user can view information about the place of the last-clicked button. But I first need to know which button is clicked. 
(I omitted some of the code, because the full code is rather long)

I tried to put this in a script tag in the head:

```
document.getElementById('button_stop1').onclick = function() {
   alert("button was clicked");
}
```

But that didn't do anything. The button did the same as before.

I also tried:

```
(function () {
    // Enables stricter rules for JavaScript
    "use strict";
    // Reference two buttons, and a textbox
    var playButton = document.getElementById("play"),
        stateTextBox = document.getElementById("state"),
        ignoreButton = document.getElementById("ignore");
    // Function that changes the value of our stateTextBox
    function changeState(event) {
        stateTextBox.value = event.target.id + " was clicked";
    }
    // Event handlers for when we click on a button
    playButton.addEventListener("click", changeState, false);
    ignoreButton.addEventListener("click", changeState, false);
}());
```

But that also did nothing. At least my first try worked when I used a button without all that kind of stuff I put in the button. So I figured it had something to do with that.

I think I can't call two functions in one button,but I ran out of things to try.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/u3wrt153/

Comment: Your fiddle works. When I copy-paste code in my own document, there comes just a popup. What should I see? Only the alert and no popup?

Comment: When I use your example in my website, when I click the button I see the popup coming up but with "have patience". What could be wrong? Apparently the function is not executed?

Comment: Are you using the same code in the fiddle? `pagecreate` event?

Comment: Oops you're right, I miscopied! Your code was a perfect solution! I'm now going to try to figure out how to make the javascript change the text of an other button and the link to which that button goes...

Comment: You can make one function instead of two separate ones, and run code based on button's ID. You can also open the popup dynamically once communication with server is done.

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed thinking of that. I'll make a new question if a new problem comes up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this off, thanks to Omar:

*HTML:*

```
<div data-role="popup" id="tt_popup">
    <p>Have patience...</p>
</div>
<a href="#tt_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn  ui-corner-all" id="button_stop1" data-transition="flip">button_stop1</a>
 <a href="#tt_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn  ui-corner-all" id="button_stop2" data-transition="flip">button_stop2</a>
```

*Javascript:*

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $("#button_stop1, #button_stop2").on("click", function () {
        $("#tt_popup p").text("Button with ID " + this.id + " was clicked");
    });
});
```

as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/u3wrt153/) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If each button calls a different function, why do you need to determine which button was clicked?

If you really must, I guess you could create something, like this (in JQuery):

```
 $(document).on("pageinit",function()
    {
      $(".ui-btn").on("click", function()
      {
        var button_value = $(this).val();
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");

       alert("You\'ve just clicked on the "+button_value+" button, with ID: "+button_id+"!");
       });
     });
```

Comment: My function is an ajax function which puts text in the popup, but I want to know which button is clicked in index.html and not in the php script which result is put in the popup by ajax. When I run your code in a script tag in the head, if I click on a button there comes just the popup and no alert.